# Give a valid statement for this regular expression

Tags: regex, expression

https://pastee.org/sg4xy

I'm not to well with regexp, hopefully someone can give me a valid statement with that, and explain how it works and maybe point me to a good site to learn regexp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation of the regular expression that you posted (created using [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com)):

```
^.syn ((([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})|([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)) [0-9]{1,5} [0-9]{1,15} [0-9]{1,15}

Assert position at the beginning of the string «^»
Match any single character that is not a line break character «.»
Match the characters “syn ” literally «syn »
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «((([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})|([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+))»
   Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})»
      Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})»
         Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 3 «([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}»
            Exactly 3 times «{3}»
            Note: You repeated the capturing group itself.  The group will capture only the last iteration.  Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations. «{3}»
            Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]{1,3}»
               Between one and 3 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «{1,3}»
            Match the character “.” literally «\.»
         Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]{1,3}»
            Between one and 3 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «{1,3}»
   Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)»
      Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 4 «([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)»
         Match a single character present in the list below «[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+»
            Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
            A character in the range between “a” and “z” «a-z»
            A character in the range between “A” and “Z” «A-Z»
            A character in the range between “0” and “9” «0-9»
            The character “_” «_»
            The character “-” «-»
         Match the character “.” literally «\.»
         Match a single character present in the list below «[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+»
            Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
            A character in the range between “a” and “z” «a-z»
            A character in the range between “A” and “Z” «A-Z»
            A character in the range between “0” and “9” «0-9»
            The character “_” «_»
            The character “-” «-»
         Match the character “.” literally «\.»
         Match a single character present in the list below «[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+»
            Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
            A character in the range between “a” and “z” «a-z»
            A character in the range between “A” and “Z” «A-Z»
            A character in the range between “0” and “9” «0-9»
            The character “_” «_»
            The character “.” «.»
            The character “-” «-»
Match the character “ ” literally « »
Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]{1,5}»
   Between one and 5 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «{1,5}»
Match the character “ ” literally « »
Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]{1,15}»
   Between one and 15 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «{1,15}»
Match the character “ ” literally « »
Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]{1,15}»
   Between one and 15 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «{1,15}»
```

Comment: @tim pietzcker, why the down vote? what did I not do or should I have done to prevent this? I provided the answer, I tried to figure out how to format my answer but I was tired and it did not happen. The answer was accepted and it appears it was done so before the down vote. I believe it would be most beneficial and educational to those of us with less StackOverflow experience and jobs that seem to prohibit us from performing tasks that accumulate 50 points a day, every day for more than 6 years straight. Please, I am not kidding, share some constructive criticism or tutelage so I improve. TY

Comment: It wasn't my downvote. I just edited your post to link to RegexBuddy.

Answer (score 0):

`^.syn ((([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})|([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)) [0-9]{1,5} [0-9]{1,15} [0-9]{1,15}`

Some example text that match above regular expression:

- `jsyn 467.317.98.0 7259 04124798576 90058`
- `xsyn 3.5.0.545 952 7940 261348`
- `Tsyn 9.47.-.u 3 12 5`

### Useful sites

- http://www.regex101.com/
- http://www.debuggex.com/